# Chrome Table not expanding div

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-tables

Currently, my site works perfectly in Firefox, IE, and Safari, but one portion does not work in Chrome.

Take a look at: `http://tinyurl . com/chxg2tb`

The table at the bottom expands beyond the content border in Chrome, instead of expanding the border like in Firefox, IE and Safari.

This has me stumped because usually errors like these happen with Firefox and IE working fine, and then the webkit browsers don't work, but in this case it is just Chrome.

For some reason the table doesn't expand the parent div, and I don't know why.

The only thing I could think of is something with overflow, but I haven't been able to get it to cooperate.

Comment: Looks fine to me in Chrome. Which part of the site exactly are you talking about?

Comment: The bottom part where the 4 logos (same one, different colors) exceed the container  (not the last 4 logos)   http://i.imgur.com/4MI9UT8.png

Comment: Nope, looks fine for me in Chrome V25 on my Macbook pro. BTW that little popup that appears when you right-click to view the source is quite annoying and useless as it's easy enough to get round. But it's annoying and a bit ten years ago.

Comment: That's strange, I've tested it on both windows and a osx and it doesn't work in my chrome V25...

Comment: is your `element.style {margin-bottom: -70px;}` in `.content-right` not all browser mange margins and padding the same.

Comment: A couple of other things worth mentioning about your page. You're using tables for layout when they should only be used for displaying tabular data. Bad practice. You're using multiple IDs on those curadebt buttons which are the same. IDs are meant to be unique. Use a class instead. You also have lots of css in the HEAD of your page. This would be better served up in an external stylesheet.

Comment: I know it isn't the best practice, either way I still don't know why mine goes over the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats NOT the best solution but you can just create a div that wraps the table and set the div css like this:

```
height: 120px;
```